# AUFilePlayer, ring buffers and render callback

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am interested in adding effects to songs played from the iTunes library.  I have constructed an auGraph as follows: AUFilePlayer -> Effects Unit -> Mixer -> RemoteIO.  There is much emphasis on the use of data buffers and render callback when playing large audio files as part of efficient memory management.  I have found in scattered sources that the AUFilePlayer (>iOS 5) somewhat reduces the need for a buffer.  Given my setup using an AUFilePlayer, should my design still include a ring buffer and render callback?

Answer (score 0):

In short, No. There is no need to add a buffer.

AUFilePlayer internally loads audio into a buffer and pulls from it as the graph requests audio.

Max